# Need simple assistance with properly tagging elements

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation

I have run this through the W3school validator and it says the "div" attribute is not allowed on "a" at this point. I'm sorry it's a stupid question to ask but it will only take a moment of your time and I appreciate the help.

```
<div class="center1">
                <h4>Do you want to apply to be a test subject? Do you also like free cake and $60? Apply now!</h4>  <a div id="redacted" href="WebForm.html"><span style="background-color: #000000">REDACTED.</span></a></div>
```

Comment: `<a div id="redacted"....` This is not valid HTML. Remove the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
<a div id="redacted" href="WebForm.html">
```

Should be changed to:

```
<a id="redacted" href="WebForm.html">
```